# select condition between 3 table

Tags: database, sqlite, conditional-statements

i have 3 table with name `city` and `state` and `project`

city

```
id_city |  name_city         
   1    |   JED
   2    |   RYD
   3    |   DMM
```

state

column city_id foreign key with city.city_id

```
 id_state | name_state | city_id
     1    |    JED 1   | 1(JED)
     2    |    RYD 1   | 2(RYD)
     3    |    RYD 2   | 2(RYD)
```

project

column state_from_city_id_table_state foreign key with state .city_id

```
id_project | city_id | state_from_city_id_table_state
      1    |     1   |  1(JED)>> (JED1)     question here 
      2    |     2   |  2(RYD)>> (RYD 1 or2) question here
```

now question is  i selected `city_id from project table` ... like 1 and i just want see `city_id from state table number 1 without number 2` in `state_id from table project`

like this `JED > JED1 only i don't wanna see RYD1 and RYD2`

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's very hard to guess what problem you are facing.

Comment: in project table column city_id if i select 1i wanna see in column state_from_city_id_table_state only number 1 without 2 
like  ......  JED > JED 1  only i don't wanna see RYD1 and RYD2

Comment: That last comment should be a included in the question, you can edit it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT ct.*, st.*, pr.* FROM `city` ct LEFT JOIN `state` st ON ct.`id_city` = st.`state_id` LEFT JOIN `project` pr ON ct.`id_city` = pr.`city_id`
```

Comment: I am joining your tables based on your foreign keys. If you think `state_from_city_id_table_state` is your foreign key for `city_id` then you can do this:
SELECT ct.*, st.*, pr.* FROM `city` ct LEFT JOIN `state` st ON ct.`id_city` = st.`state_id` LEFT JOIN `project` pr ON ct.`id_city` = pr.`state_from_city_id_table_state`

This is what you wanted?
If not then please tell the final result you want.

Comment: amm not like this 
if u sign up like in any website government
u need chose state and than city
u have many state and each state have private city
i need like this 
sorry i'm  Floundering ... now city JED if i chose state i want JED1 appear if i click on comb only i don't want any RYD

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: it's solved Left Join that what i need it 
after practice this code is true but need change some word in code